# Opencv Mingw Build

Tags: c++, opencv, mingw

After trying without succed to install opencv with Mingw and codeblocks, i finnaly give up and download the precompiled libs from :

https://github.com/drewcrawford/drew-face/tree/master/opencv/build

But when i try to run some opencv code, my application crashed when it start and i have this message :

"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005). Click OK to close the application."

Her is my code test :

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    cv::Mat image;
    image = cv::imread("4010194A00101a_090.bmp",0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: terrible idea. won't work, since you do not have the **exact** mingw version those libs were built with. this is exactly the reason, why they stopped delivering prebuilt mingw libs. do not try to cheat. go back to start. you will **have** to build from src, or use vs express.

Comment: Yes i know. But i really need to used with mignw because my projct is build on mingw. Well i guess i should do what you say. The problem is that i try to do it but i have error in the build part when i use mingw32-make. it give me many errors. Well i will do a clean build and i will return to this post if something goes wrong. Thank you very much

Comment: please do so. folks here will try to help

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. It seems that the problem was my mingw version. I installed a new version a it works.